# Offset to code location in release-build of Qt 5.12 project with mingw730 32 bit

Tags: c++, qt, mingw32

I have a Qt-project that includes a massive customer legacy code base (that I'm unfortunately not at liberty to post). Debug builds with qmake/QtCreator work, but release builds crash even before hitting main. My suspicion is some static initialisation. When I run the debugger in Qt Creator, I get a segmentation fault and a disassembly trace. No symbols, no really usable stack trace. Any hints on how to approach this? Can I resolve the process address where the crash occurs to a symbol in my code?

Edit: the disassembly looks like this:

```
0:000> u
ProgrammName+0x39b40:
00439b40 8b842468010000  mov     eax,dword ptr [esp+168h]
00439b47 8384246801000004 add     dword ptr [esp+168h],4
00439b4f 89fa            mov     edx,edi
00439b51 8b00            mov     eax,dword ptr [eax]
00439b53 85c0            test    eax,eax
00439b55 0f8461f6ffff    je      ProgrammName+0x391bc (004391bc)
00439b5b 85db            test    ebx,ebx
00439b5d 8d4801          lea     ecx,[eax+1]
0:000> u
ProgrammName+0x39b60:
00439b60 0fb600          movzx   eax,byte ptr [eax]
00439b63 0f8ef7000000    jle     ProgrammName+0x39c60 (00439c60)
00439b69 84c0            test    al,al
00439b6b 750d            jne     ProgrammName+0x39b7a (00439b7a)
00439b6d e9ee000000      jmp     ProgrammName+0x39c60 (00439c60)
00439b72 84c0            test    al,al
00439b74 0f8442f6ffff    je      ProgrammName+0x391bc (004391bc)
00439b7a 83eb01          sub     ebx,1
```

My thinking is that the `ProgramName+0xXXXX` addresses should somehow be translatable into a symbol somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution: https://forum.qt.io/topic/2363/solved-how-to-build-release-with-debug-info-mingw/4

Basically it's about building for release, but keeping debug symbols. The addition to my Qt project file was

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE =
```